# No gears after serpentine belt replaced

Tags: automatic-transmission

After running car hot after serpentine belt broke, i replaced it. But now i dont have any gears! Reverse or drive or first or second?  Could it be as simple as adding transmission fluid?

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid level?

Comment: Year/make/model/engine ?